# How do I make a tkinter button change colors every time I click it

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import*
window = Tk()
color=['red','blue','purple']

def chgcolor():
    for i in color:
        mybutton.config(bg=i)
window.title('my first python gui')
mybutton=Button(window,text='change color',command=chgcolor)
mybutton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make the button change colors to red, then blue, then purple, then back to the original color every time I click the button, but for now, it only turns purple no matter how many times I click it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use for loop inside `chgcolor()`.  Use `itertools.cycle()` on the colors and `next(color)` to get the next color and update the button inside `chgcolor()`:

```py
# avoid using wildcard import
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('my first python gui')

def chgcolor():
    # get the next color from the color list
    mybutton.config(bg=next(color))

mybutton = tk.Button(window, text='change color', command=chgcolor)
mybutton.pack()

# create a color cycle list
color = cycle(['red','blue','purple',mybutton['bg']])

window.mainloop()
```